# Linking GSL fails with icc but not gcc

Tags: gsl, icc

I am trying to compile my programs using icc and not gcc, using the GNU Scientific Library (gsl). For the previous year, this worked perfectly, but when I had to reinstall icc when I renewed my license, I was unable to link gsl at compile time. However, with gcc it works perfectly fine. I don't really know what is going on, I have tried reinstalling gsl, icc, and everything but nothing seems to work. Upon trying to link gsl, I get the following error

```
ld: library not found for -lgsl
```

Comment: try ``gsl-config --libs`` to specify the location of gsl?

Comment: Could you pleas provide more details as such questions sometimes are platform-specific. First, we need 'ldconfig -v | grep gsl' and your distro.

Comment: @zmwang this fixed it! thank you so much!!